# Making "Read More" post link w/ Markdown [POSTACH.IO]

Tags: markdown, evernote

This is my first time using Markdown, and it seems pretty simple. I am using it on an opinion blog I have for Postach.io

I am used to Tumblr's WYSIWYG, with the "READ MORE" tag option; however, postach.io only allows READ MORE by limiting characters. How can I use Markdown to make a READ MORE tag, directing it to the permalink of my post?

--> I use the Evernote Desktop program to create my blog entries, and have the markdown option selected online.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you still need an answer - and I needed one, which is how I ended up at this page in the first place - Use [[MORE]] in the spot where you want the break to happen. It's a tumblr-specific thing, and it works in both HTML and Markdown mode.

Example:

> Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. [[MORE]] Pellentesque quis lacinia orci, vel fringilla quam. In vitae tortor vitae purus volutpat consequat. Pellentesque sagittis libero vitae hendrerit dignissim. Cras laoreet.

Displays on people's dashboards as:

> Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit.
>
> Read More →

With the "Read More" linking to the full post, as it would if you had added it in the HTML or WYSIWYG editor:

> Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Pellentesque quis lacinia orci, vel fringilla quam. In vitae tortor vitae purus volutpat consequat. Pellentesque sagittis libero vitae hendrerit dignissim. Cras laoreet.

Answer (score 0):

Since postach.io doesn't support it, you can't do it. Well, not without quite a lot of work anyway.

You could create two posts, one with full content and the other with the short version. Post the full version first, but hidden (assuming there is someway to do this). Then create a normal markdown link in the short version to the long version and post the short version normally.

Comment: This was my first idea, but after some research, to have anything published, it needs to be tagged with "published"... Then it would still appear on the blog's homepage and there would be duplicates. Thank you though.